# Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 1 when installing drivelist npm module

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-7

I am trying to get a repository I worn on to work on my laptop. But when I try to run `npm-install` I get this error:

```
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:305:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\programing\nodejs\node-smart-tv\SmartTV\node_modules\drivelist
gyp ERR! node -v v13.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! drivelist@6.4.6 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the drivelist@6.4.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-28T16_43_04_398Z-debug.log
```

I connected to my home PC with teamviewer and tried to install that package there and it worked. The package requires MSVC to be compiled. Computer where it works is Windows 10 PC with visual studio 2017. The computer where it doesn't work is Windows 7 and also visual studio 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self answering because this could save someone a lot of headache. There was a startup script in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` registry which was failing and thus returning `1`, this probably broke the shell scripts. Replacing that key's value with empty string fixed the problem.

Comment: This was also my problem, I added an Autorun reg key to fix my blank conhost window but it caused this.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when trying to use electron-build to rebuild the serialport module. Tomáš' response solved this for me, just to reiterate:

1. Winkey + R -> regedit
2. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
3. Remove anything inside the AutoRun value so it is left blank
4. Reload CMD/restart IDE